# filter data frame in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a simple shiny app, that takes as input a data frame in the following structure:

```
A B C D E F G Y
1 1 1 x x x   x
1 2 1 x   x
1 2 2   x x   x
1 2 2   x   x x
2 1 1 x  x  x
```

I would like to be able to filter the data in R shiny based on the value of the columns (D,E,F, G and Y) given as checkboxes. The checkboxes are grouped in the following way:

```
Category1 Checkboxes (D, E)
Category2 Checkboxes (F, G, Y)
```

One solution I implemented, is to subset (keeping the corresponding category columns) and convert this table into long format, and make the filtering based on the `key,value` pair. However, I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to make the conversion.

Can anyone guide me how to implement this?

Here is reproducible data:

```
dput(test)
structure(list(A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), B = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), C = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), D = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), E = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), F = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), G = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor"), Y = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "x"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

- Blank is simply `NA`, which means that rows where the column contains only `NA`, should not be considered in the filtering.
- The checkboxes are grouped as in this example:
  Category 1 (`D` and `E`) means that, in this category, either `D` or `E`, or both can be selected.

When I check the box `E`, only the rows where `E` contains an `x` should stay in the filtered output.

If I check another box, say `G`, the list of rows will be reduced to the rows where `E` and `G` contain an `x`

I hope this clarify the problem better.

Here is my code:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)  
library(plotly)

dashboardPage(skin="blue", dashboardHeader(title = "test"),

              dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(
                  menuItem("Export Page", tabName = "main", icon = icon("dashboard"))

                )
              ),
              dashboardBody(
                tags$head(
                  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
                ),
                #tags$head(tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/png", href = "favicon.png"), tags$title("LinkAnalysis")),
                tabItems(
                  tabItem(tabName = "main",
                          sidebarPanel(
                            fluidPage(
                              uiOutput("checkboxes_cat1"),
                              uiOutput("checkboxes_cat2")
                            )
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            tableOutput("table")
                          )
                  )
                )
              )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


test <- read.table('test.csv', sep=';', header =  T)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$checkboxes_cat1 <- renderUI({
    return(checkboxGroupInput("cat1", "Category 1", choices = levels(as.factor(colnames(test[4:5])))))
  })

  output$checkboxes_cat2 <- renderUI({
    return(checkboxGroupInput("cat2", "Category 2", choices = levels(as.factor(colnames(test[5:7])))))
  })

  filtered<-reactive({ 


  #d <- test[,input$cat1,drop=FALSE] 
  #d
    #### the filtering should be done here
    test

  })

  output$table<-renderTable({

    filtered()

    })

})
```

Comment: Can you clarify your data structure? What is in the blanks `NA`, `""`, something else? Is it a `matrix` or is it a `data.frame`? (a matrix can only have one class, but your example seems to have both numbers and letters, so it looks like a data frame, not a matrix). How is the checkbox grouping relevant? When you say checkboxes D and E are grouped together, does that mean they are either both checked or both unchecked? How is the filtering supposed to work? If checkbox D is not checked, does that mean only rows where D doesn't have an X? Or does it mean no filtering on D? Or something else?

Comment: As my above comment illustrates, I think you need to provide a lot more information. Please provide sample data in a copy/pasteable format too (use `dput()`!), this will clear up any data structure questions AND make it easier for people to help you. Also please provide several examples of input and the desired result (e.g., what boxes are checked, and what the corresponding output is).

Comment: @Gregor I updated the question, I hope this is more clear now

Comment: This is much improved! I'm still a little confused about the grouping. It seems like it matters for your shiny app, but it doesn't matter for this question. If this is correct, please remove it from the question because it is confusing. If not, please explain how it matters for this question and answer. Does the answer you are looking for need to treat checkboxes D and E differently than boxes F, G, and Y?

Comment: @Gregor what i mean with grouping here, is basically the following code:

`radioButtons("cat1", "Category1", choices = c('D','E'))`  where the choices are 
 automatically extracted from the table

Comment: Okay, so that's pretty different that what you describe. Could you share a *minimal* code for the shiny app so we can see what's going on? In your question, you use the term "checkbox" and it sounds like you have five checkboxes. The way checkboxes behave, they can all individually be checked or unchecked. In this comment, you say you are using radio buttons, which behave differently, requiring exactly one selection each. This clarification makes me worried that there are more differences between your question and your actual use case, which is why I ask for a reproducible example.

Comment: @Gregor True, it should be checkboxes and radioButtons, I will share a reproducible example of the code to clarify things better

Comment: @Gregor I added the code, and where the filtering should take place in the code based on the details i mentioned in the original question. I hope this helps